# Define a first order logic structure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Let $L$ be a first order language with equality such as $F_{0} = \{a,b\}$, $F_{1}=\{g,h,f\}$, $F_{2}=\{f\}$, $R_{1}=\{S,T\}$ and $R_{2}=\{R,Q\}$. For each of the following propositions indicate a structure of $L$ where it is true and one where it is false.

- $\forall y \exists x (x \not= g(y))$
- $\forall x (T(x) \implies \forall y Q(x,y))$

Comment: What are $F_0  = \{ a,b \}, F_1 = \{ g,h,f \}$, etc ???

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA According to my teacher F are functional symbols. The ones in F0 are constants. R are relations.

Comment: Thus , **I imagine**, that $F_0$ is the collection of *constants* symbols, $F_1$ the collection of *unary* function symbols, $F_2$ that of *binary*, and so on withe relation symbols. If so, for the first sentence you need only an interpretation $g^A$ for the unary function symbol $g$.

Comment: Can it be something like $g^A(n) = n, n \in \mathbb{N}$? In this case for all $y$ there is a $x$ such that $x≠g(y)$ = $x≠y$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber in 1) I tried $g^A(n) = n \in \mathbb{N}$ but I don't really know if it's true in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that works for the first one: for any y, all you need to have is some x that does not equal y ... Which for natural numbers you always have.

Comment: This works for either true and false right? Because for all y there is a x where $y ≠ x$ and $y = x$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was only commenting on the true case.  That is, if you pick $g^A(n) = n$, then the first statement is true since you simply pick $y \not = x$. To make it false, you'll need to define $g^A$ to be something else. In fact, to think about it, you need a different domain to make it false!

Comment: What if my domain is the set $\{0\}$ and $g^A(n) = 0$, statement 1) is false in this case?

Comment: Yes, you got it! You could only make that one false with a domain of exactly 1 object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do a lot of different things with the natural numbers (0,1,2,3,...), so that is usually a good domain to play with.

Indeed, for the first one, you can interpret $g$ as the successor function: the statement will be true since for any $y$ you can always pick 0 for $x$.

For the second one, you have a 1-place predicate T (so interpret this as some kind of property of natural numbers ... like 'x is an even number' or 'x is a prime number' or ...) and a 2-place predicate Q (so interpret this as a relation between 2 numbers ... such as 'x is smaller than y' or 'x is divisible by y' or ...).  Lots of options here: I am sure you can figure out something that will work!

Comment: For 2) since I have a implication I can simplify it to be the negation of $T(X)$ and change the implication symbol to an or such that it is like: $¬T(x) ∨ Q(x,y)$ and then I just need to define a structure that is true for $T$ or for $Q$ right?

Comment: For example, if I define a structure like:$A$ is the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and $T^A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \space is \space even\}$ it would be false because in $\mathbb{N}$ we have odd numbers so $¬T(x)$ would be true and $∀x(T(x)⟹∀yQ(x,y))$ would consequently be true.

Comment: No, that wouldn't quite work, since the statement stars with $\forall x$, so you need $T(x)$ to be false for *all* natural numbers, not just the odd numbers. Your basic idea is good though ... Could you maybe come up with some property that *no* natural numbers have?

Comment: Would it work if I say that $T^A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \lt 0 \}$?

Comment: Yes, that will work!

Comment: And in order for it to be false could I say: $T^A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \ge 0\}$ and $Q^A = \{(0,1)\}$?

Comment: Yes, correct!  In fact, you can even just simply say $Q^A=\{\}$. And for $T^A$, all you then need is something that does include at least one number, e.g. $T^A=\{1\}$.